# Concavity and Convexity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

A set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be convex if $tx + (1-t)y \in X$ for all $x,y \in X$ and $t \in (0,1)$. Given a convex set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, a function $f: X  \to \mathbb R$ is said to be concave if $f(tx + (1-t)y) \ge tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in X$ and $t \in (0,1)$.

1) Show that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb R$ is concave iff 
    $\sum_{i=1}^r t_if(x_i) \le f\left(\sum_{i=1}^r t_ix_i\right)$

for every positive integer r, for all $x_1, \dots, x_r \in \mathbb R^n$, and all $t_1,\dots,t_r \in (0,1)$ with $\sum_{i=1}^r t_i = 1$

2) Use (1) to show that $\prod_{i=1}^r x_i^{t_i} \le \sum_{i=1}^r t_ix_i$
   for all non negative $x_1, \dots, x_r \in \mathbb R$ and all $t_1,\dots,t_r \in (0,1)$ with $\sum_{i=1}^r t_i = 1$

3) Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is **convex** iff the set
     $\{(x,r) \in  \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}  \mid  f(x) \le r \}$ 
   is convex.

Comment: why isnt my text getting formatted? :O

Comment: You have to put your LaTeX commands between \$  \$

Comment: I followed the MathJax basic tutorial.
Not even a single one is working. or do we need to add something extra to activate these formats?
check \ge

Comment: please yous \to for $\to$ and \mathbb{R} for $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Please, see my edits to your code for (1) and (2).

Comment: @n.c i did that. but whats the point. nothing is being reflected.
 I cant see any edits. moreover why isnt the 'formatting' being reflected finally when I am following all what is written in MathJax. or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you just copied the output from MathJax. Use your LaTeX commands directly here. For example: at the beginning of your post: X ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n, edit it in the following way: X\subset\mathbb{R}^n and put everything between \$ \$

Comment: thanx a lot n.c. $ came to my rescue. :)

Comment: Source of this question: from the past years question papers of an exam.

Comment: I suspect the inequality is reversed in 3).

Comment: nope. I checked again. its $f(x) \le r$ only. Can u please solve it anyway?

Comment: Item (3) will be easier to prove if, ignoring what you found in the source, you reverse the inequality and use $f(x)\geq r$.  (It's generally easier to prove true statements than false ones.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think you are right. There seems to be an error in the paper. so I have edited the 3rd part by changing "$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is **concave** iff" by "$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is **convex** iff". Could you please tell me now, how can we solve this??

Comment: @AndreasBlass hey I think this problem is solved now. (after the changes suggested by you). thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part 1), try induction on $r$. For 2), think about log. For 3) think about the pairs $(x, f(x)), (y, f(y))$.

I'm being somewhat mysterious because I think these are healthy exercises to solve for oneself.

EDIT:

Hey sorry for the delay. For the first part, the second condition implies concavity so we only need to prove the first condition implies the second. For the base case, this is easy. Suppose it holds for k and pick $x_1, ..., x_k, x_{k+1} \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $t_1, ..., t_{k+1} \in (0, 1)$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} t_i=1$. Now, let $x'_k=\frac{t_kx_k+t_{k+1}x_{k+1}}{t_k+t_{k+1}}$ and $t'_k= t_k+t_{k+1}$. Then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} t_i + t'_k=1$ and by inductive assumption we therefore have $t'_kf(x'_k)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} t_if(x_i)$ $ \leq f( t'_kx'_k+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} t_ix_i)=f(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} t_ix_i)$. To finish up, we need to show that $t_kf(x_k)+t_{k+1}f(x_{k+1}) \leq t'_kf(x'_k)$. Now, $0<t_k+t_{k+1}<1$ so there is some $r \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $rt_k+rt_{k+1}=1$. Then by the base case, $rt_kf(x_k)+rt_{k+1}f(x_{k+1}) \leq f(rt_kx_k+rt_{k+1}x_{k+1})=f(rt'_kx'_k)=f(x'_k)$. But by definition, $r= \frac{1}{t_k+t_{k+1}}$ and so dividing by $r$, this gives what we want.

Comment: thanx for your answer. I am trying it right now.
As far as you being mysterious is concerned: I can give you the link, from where these questions are taken. This question was asked in an exam in the year 2004.

Comment: Cool. Also, if anything I wrote is too vague, I can definitely clarify.

Comment: First part: I am not able to prove it via induction. Base case: it is obvious because r=1 so $t_1f(x_1) \le f(t_1x_1)$ and $t_1$ = 1. but I got stuck when proving it for r=k+1 assuming the inequality to hold good for r=k;i.e. $t_1f(x_1) + ... +t_kf(x_k)$ + $t_{k+1}x_{k+1}$ $\le f(t_1x_1 + ... t_kx_k$ + $t_{k+1}x_{k+1}$) . how to prove this??

Comment: Alexander I am still waiting for you to clarify more. thanx

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my computer for a day. I have updated my answer to give a more thorough solution to part 1.

Comment: I am not comfortable with the the inequality which you wrote just before the phrase **"to finish up"**. shouldn't the RHS of that inequality become equal to $f(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}t_ix_i + t_kx'_k + t_{k+1}x'_k)$ instead $f(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}t_ix_i)$ (which u have written).

Comment: $t_kx'_k+t_{k+1}x'_k=(t_k+t_{k+1})x'_k=(t_k+t_{k+1}) \frac{t_kx_k+t_{k+1}x_{k+1}}{t_k+t_{k+1}}=t_kx_k+t_{k+1}x_{k+1}$.

The point of defining $x'_k$ in the way I do is to get that equation to work. The idea is I want $x'_k$ to be a sort of 'weighted combination' of the last two terms so that I can reduce the length of the sum by one and apply the inductive assumption.

Comment: its simply brilliant. I never thought induction was such a powerful tool. Thanx.
I'll now try part 2 and part 3 with your hints.

Comment: Alexander : part 2 was obvious once part 1 is proven because here we are just replacing f with log. But please elaborate upon part 3.

Comment: part 3 was also done by the help of one of the members of this community. EVentually, your hint came into play :)
thanx a lot @Alexander

Comment: No problem and I'm glad you worked them out! Sorry about part 3). I have a bad habit of thinking I know how proofs should go and then misreading inequalities so that my arguments work.